# Equivalent PROCV in PHP

Tags: php

I have the table:

```
class   | name  | 
--------+-------+
mage    | merlim|
warrior | gatz  |
rogue   | zoro  |
```

How can I get the name of a given class? 
It's like the PROCV function of Excel.

In my PHP code:

```
//$table is the result returned from a call to the db shown above

$classes_required = array("mage","warrior","rogue");
foreach($classes_required as $class){
    $$class = PROCV_equivalent($table, $class);
}
```

Result of var_export($table);

```
 array ( 
     0 => array ( 0 => 'class', 1 => 'name'), 
     1 => array ( 0 => 'mage', 1 => 'merlim'), 
     2 => array ( 0 => 'warrior', 1 => 'gatz'),  
     3 => array ( 0 => 'rogue', 1 => 'zoro'),  
 )
```

Comment: If this is a database table, `SELECT name from mytable where class='warrior'`.... if it's an HTML table, then you're going to need to do some parsing

Comment: Yes, it is the result of a db search. Altough I need all the results, so I was wondering if there is a better solution instead of doing n-queries to the db.

Comment: Well what are you doing with it when you read it from the database? Are you fetching it into a PHP array? If so, what does that array look like?

Comment: @MarkBaker I added some PHP code.

Comment: Show what $table looks like: do a `var_export($table)` and show the result of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an associative array that maps class to name:

```
$classname = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < count($table); $i++) {
  $row = $table[$i];
  $classname[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}

foreach ($classes_required as $class) {
  $name = $classname[$class];
}
```